# Do Mormons agree with the Apostle Paul when he said at Acts 16:31 to the Philippian Jailer, "Believe on the Lord Jesus Christ and you shall be saved."

Tags: soteriology, lds

At verse 32 Paul spoke the word of the Lord to him "together" with all who were in his house. Vs33, "And he took them that very hour of the night and washed their wounds, and immediately he was baptized, he and all his household."

Verse 34, "And he brought them into his house and set food before them, and rejoiced greatly, having believed in God with his whole household." Now, this incident happened within an hour so how does Mormon teaching reconcile this with the many "saving ordinances" that your religion tells us we must perform in order to earn our eternal salvation?

The Apostle Paul did not mention any Masonic/occult rituals, the covenants, the work or the pre-requisites required of Mormons. Nothing about the mandate that men must join a so-called "Melchizedek Priesthood." No secret handshakes or passwords are represented. No tithing, "sustaining the prophet" or temples or interrogations to determine worthiness."

Paul's answer let him know he must "believe" rather than "do." in order to be saved. At John 6:28-29 the people ask Jesus, "What shall we do, that we might work the works of God?" Jesus replied, "This is the work of God, that you believe on Him who He hath sent."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What roles do faith and works play in the LDS/Mormon understanding of salvation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6119/what-roles-do-faith-and-works-play-in-the-lds-mormon-understanding-of-salvation)

Comment: The demons believe James 2:14.  Faith apart from works is useless  James 2:20

Comment: @Kris But at the point of believing, no superficial judgment can be made as to the fruitfulness of a particular individual and what is the exact _nature_ of their faith. Time will tell. But that does not preclude a discerning Minister (or Apostle) ajudging that an individual is clearly penitent and clearly in a way of genuine faith and that there may be unequivocal exhortation to believe the gospel, irrespective of present attainments.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it treats pejoratively the beliefs of a different denomination from the asker.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Excuse me but I was unaware that you had the ability to know the operation of one's mind? You used the word "Pejorative." Expressing contempt or disapproval. Contempt: the feeling that a person is beneath consideration, worthless or deserving scorn. I quoted Scripture and ask if Mormons agree with it, the answer was "yes" What I may say about someone and how I feel about them are two different things. Read what love incarnate said to the Jews at Matthew 23:29-27. Was Jesus pejorative? Did He have contempt for them? Read vs 37, because that's how I feel for those that are lost.

Comment: The tone of your third paragraph came across that way.  Your use of the term "occult" seems to me out of place. As nobody else had that impression, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

> Do Mormons agree with the Apostle Paul...?

Yes, except belief isn't just a word. This is clarified in [Helaman 14:13](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bofm/hel/14?lang=eng&id=13#p13)

> 13 And if ye believe on his name ye will repent of all your sins, that thereby ye may have a remission of them through his merits.

And this is exemplified in vs 33 (Acts 16) when they are baptized. They didn't just need to say they believed, but they acted on that belief.

> how does Mormon teaching reconcile this?

[Baptism](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/baptism?lang=eng) is the first saving ordinance of the gospel. So the jailer took the first step, no reconciliation required. Other saving [ordinances](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/ordinances?lang=eng) include:

- confirmation
- ordination to the [Melchizedek Priesthood](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/melchizedek-priesthood?lang=eng) (for men)
- the temple [endowment](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/endowment?lang=eng)
- marriage sealing

[Isaiah 28:9-13](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/isa/28?lang=eng&id=9-13#p9) teaches us learning and progressing in the gospel is a process.

> 9 ¶ Whom shall he teach knowledge? and whom shall he make to understand doctrine? them that are weaned from the milk, and drawn from the breasts.

> 10 For precept must be upon precept, precept upon precept; line upon line, line upon line; here a little, and there a little:

> 11 For with stammering lips and another tongue will he speak to this people.

> 12 To whom he said, This is the rest wherewith ye may cause the weary to rest; and this is the refreshing: yet they would not hear.

> 13 But the word of the Lord was unto them precept upon precept, precept upon precept; line upon line, line upon line; here a little, and there a little; that they might go, and fall backward, and be broken, and snared, and taken.

---

> Apostle Paul did not mention any Masonic/occult rituals, the covenants, the work or the pre-requisites required of Mormons

The ordinances besides baptism, all require baptism first. Just like sealings can't be done unless one has been endowed. Each ordinance is a step. Just as babies can't eat meat right away, but have milk first.<sup>1</sup> Why would Paul introduce more ordinances when the man hadn't been baptized yet? Also verse 32 does say `And they spake unto him the word of the Lord, and to all that were in his house.` which doesn't give the exact words spoken by Paul, he could've taught the principle of ordinances and covenants.

> No tithing, "sustaining the prophet" or temples or interrogations to determine worthiness.

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints don't base everything off of a single scripture or teaching of one apostle. Instead we really on all scriptures containing words from multiple apostles and prophets together. The church of Jesus Christ also rely on modern day prophets and apostles to guide us. The gospel of Jesus Christ is a magnificent tapestry of truth “fitly framed” and woven together.<sup>2</sup> Paul also said in Ephesians 1:10

> That in the dispensation of the fulness of times he might gather together in one all things in Christ, both which are in heaven, and which are on earth; even in him:

In regards to the "interrogations to determine worthiness" all the questions are [available](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2019/10/57nelson?lang=eng)

Jesus also said in [John 3:5](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/john/3?lang=eng)

> 5 Jesus answered, Verily, verily, I say unto thee, **Except a man be born of water and of the Spirit, he cannot enter into the kingdom of God.**

which sounds like a **do**. The Church of Jesus Christ state in [Article of Faith 4](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/pgp/a-of-f/1.4?lang=eng)

> 4 We believe that the first principles and ordinances of the Gospel are: first, **Faith in the Lord Jesus Christ**; second, Repentance; third, **Baptism by immersion for the remission of sins**; fourth, Laying on of hands for the gift of the Holy Ghost.

Which covers both **believing** and **doing**, as faith leads to action (such as baptism)

1 [1 Corinthians 3:2-3](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/1-cor/3.2-3?lang=eng)

<sub>2 [Gather Together in One All Things in Christ](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2018/10/gather-together-in-one-all-things-in-christ?lang=eng), Elder David A Bednar</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133672/discussion-on-answer-by-depperm-do-mormons-agree-with-the-apostle-paul-when-he-s).